# Loading the usercontrol asynchronously on click of a button

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have 2 usercontrol, each in different-different updatepanel. Also I have a button outside these 2 updatepanels. On this button click I am trying to call the method in usercontrol.

It doesn't displays the data till button click is not complete, so my both user controls load at the same time. I want to load these user control  asynchronously i.e as soon as method in that usercontrol finishes, I want data to be displayed. What should I change to make it work properly.

The method in  usercontrol is basically creates dynamic html for the user control.

I am calling the user control method in button click, so it is happening sequentially. UpdatePanel's Unload event occurs at the end, is there a way I can raise this event from button click.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly (which isn't that easy), you need some sort of `FinishedLoading` event in your user controls and have its delegates on your page where you'd set their visibility to true.

Comment: controls are always in visible state, just the thing is on button click I take some parameters to the usercontrol and loads it again. Both control are loading but I want them to load indepandently i.e as soon as method for first finishes it should load the first control while second keeps on loading.

Comment: oh I see. One button two controls. So, your options are: 2 jQuery  $.ajax calls or .NET multi-threading. Look it up.

Comment: ya that is what I am doing, both controls are in updatepanel. so it should load dynamically

Comment: no they shouldn't because update panels will load until your button click event is finished.

Comment: can't it be done through delegates, I believe it should work with delegation

Comment: @Nits it sounds to me like you've skipped over a couple articles on Multithreading/AJAX, picked up a couple terms, but not grasped it just yet.  Although delegates _can be_ used (and in fact, often are) when threading, your last comment makes no sense so I'd recommend going and looking at just **one** of the two topics.  Multithreading in code is not the same as AJAX/Async HttpRequests, despite sharing some common principles.  From what I can make of your question, have a look into AJAX.  You shouldn't need to write any real multithreaded code I don't think.